# Regex pattern for timestamp

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regex patern for this:

```
[0:00:07]
```

This is my code:

```
string pattern = "[[0-9]{1,1}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}]";
```

I've got such a result: `0:00:07]`. As you can see, my regex misses the first `'['`. How can I resolve it?

Comment: escape `[]`..........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to match literal `[` or `]` in a regex, you need to escape it:

```
string pattern = @"\[[0-9]:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\]";
```

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5B0-9%5D%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%5C%5D&i=%5B0%3A00%3A07%5D)

Note, that `{1,1}` is equal to no quantifier (i.e. the preceding subpattern will be matched once).

Also, it should be noted that the final `]` does not need escaping as .NET regex engine will treat it as a literal (as it cannot parse it as part of a character class delimiter. HOWEVER, it is a good idea to keep your pattern *unambiguous*, and escape special characters wherever they appear inside the pattern (it will be very handy if you want to port your regex to another platform).

Answer (score 3):

Escape the first square brace.

```
   \[[[0-9]{1,1}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}]
```

This should work. There are alternate representations as in other answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
\[[0-9]{1,1}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\]
```

you need to escape the []